# Проблема с альфа-каналом в Shader Graph Unity

Tags: unity3d, shader-graph

У меня есть простой шейдер, который искажает спрайт в зависимости от времени. В предпросмотре Shader Graph он выглядит так, как я задумывал: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, при попытке использовать этот шейдер в сцене, прозрачность спрайта ломается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо того, чтобы использовать альфа-канал из шейдера, спрайт просто обрезается по Outline из настроек импорта.
Вот сам shader graph:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй взять альфу из текстуры до изменения UV, скорее всего прозрачность страдает от этого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]